# how to properly access a superclass view controller's IBOutlet property from its subclass?

Tags: ios, swift

how to properly access a superclass view controller's IBOutlet property from its subclass?

I have a DetailViewController and An AddViewController which is a subclass of the DetailViewController. In DetailVC, I have a bunch of textViews as IBOutlet properties connected from storyboard. I want to use these textViews in AddVC, but always found nil.

```
// These textViews are connected to storyboard's DetailViewController from DetailViewController
@IBOutlet var textViews: [KMPlaceholderTextView]!


// I'm trying to access those textViews from AddViewController which is a subclass of DetailViewController, but they are nil
class JLAddViewController: JLDetailViewController {
    // MARK: - *****数据源*****
    // 用来接收主控制器搜索框上的单词
    var word:String?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // 打开每个textView的输入功能
        textViews.forEach {
            $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
            $0.isEditable = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the instance of `JLAddViewController`?

Comment: storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.addVCReuseIdentifier) as? JLAddViewController

Comment: And have you connected the various objects in that scene to the outlets?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you Sir, I got it, seems like I did a lot of redundant work creating that subclass stuff. Take care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view controllers in the storyboard are not classes but instances. The interface and outlets you designed for an instance of DetailViewController belong to that one instance, not to some other instance and certainly not to an instance of a subclass.

Comment: Thank you, sir, but what should I do if I want to use the detailVC instance I designed in storyboard as a template, because addVC is pretty much the same with DetailVC.

Comment: You can do that, but you need to explicitly assign all of the views in that second scene to the IBOutlets.  You may be better off creating a single scene and a single class and having that one view controller handle both the show detail and add detail modes

Comment: “but what should I do if I want to use the detailVC instance I designed in storyboard as a template” I would That is a whole different question. My job is to explain why the subclass outlets are nil.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you Sir, I got it, seems like I did a lot of redundant work creating that subclass stuff. Take care!

Comment: @matt You are right, I understand. With your answer and Paulw11's, I figured out what to do next. Thank you and take care!